# Form validation not being updated when item is removed from the model. Bug?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, angularjs

I started using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) lately, and I think I ran into a weird bug.

---

First, here's some working code:

**View:**

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <form name="form">

        <div ng-repeat="phone in phoneNumbers">
            <input ng-model="phone.number" required />
            <button ng-click="deleteNumber($index)">Delete Number</button>
        </div>

        <button ng-click="addNumber()">Add Number</button>

        <input type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" />

    </form>

</body>
```

**Controller:**

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ( $scope ) {

    $scope.phoneNumbers = [{
        number: '212-123-4567'
    }];

    $scope.addNumber = function () {
        $scope.phoneNumbers.push({
            number: ''
        });
    };

    $scope.deleteNumber = function ( index ) {
        $scope.phoneNumbers.splice(index, 1);
    };

});
```

Here's the Plunkr: [**Working example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ta4tXI8KUkRjXpv2PkaB?p=preview).

I think the code is pretty straightforward: there's an `ng-repeat` displaying every phone number, which you can edit/delete. If a phone number is added, it can't be empty; the submit button will be disabled if there's an empty phone number.

---

The issue arises when the submit button is placed above the `ng-repeat`. If you add a phone number, leave it empty, and then delete it, the submit button will stay disabled:

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <form name="form">

        <input type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" />

        <div ng-repeat="phone in phoneNumbers">
            <input ng-model="phone.number" required />
            <button ng-click="deleteNumber($index)">Delete Number</button>
        </div>

        <button ng-click="addNumber()">Add Number</button>

    </form>

</body>
```

Here's the plunkr: [**Broken example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pJGQNN45hkfiWfoOfYv5?p=preview).

---

I love AngularJS, but this has nearly driven me insane. I've spent upwards of 20 hours chasing this stupid bug. Since a usual demo has the submit button on the bottom, I couldn't reproduce the issue. I had to take my actual code, and slowly reduce the code to the barest minimum. It is a very large and complex app, and... Well, I'll stop whining now.

My question is two-fold:

1. Is this a bug? I even tried this with the unstable branch (1.1.3), and it works the exact same way.
2. What can I do to work around it, *without changing source order*. I know I can move around my submit button via CSS, but in my case that's not really an option; I need the submit button to be the first thing in the form.

---

**P.S. [Here's a video of it in action](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pg-Itozaqrw)**.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but it appears that if you change your submit element to a basic button instead of an `<input>`, it works as expected, e.g. `<button ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Submit</button>`.  Does that help as a work-around?

Comment: was playing with broken plunkr and placing `{{phoneNumbers}}` in html to visualize what was happening to object also stopped the issue and output was correct. Obviously not a workaround but interesting

Comment: +1 for a proper way to ask a question on angularjs tag.

Comment: @Marc - [I couldn't get it to work](http://plnkr.co/edit/VvjGrNJ2o6M7ojBWJHkJ?p=preview).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this is an active bug.

See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1572

In that bug, a workaround was posted which uses a hidden counter that is incremented when fields are added/removed - this is used to force Angular to re-validate the form.

An example jsFiddle was given: http://jsfiddle.net/HhcXT/

In template:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-bind="abc" />
```

In controller:

```
$scope.removeYears = function(item) {
    var index = $.inArray(item, $scope.years)
    $scope.years.splice(index, 1);        //remove element
    $scope.abc += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Out of curiosity: what search term did you use to find this bug report? I had searched around for quite some time before I posted this, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I think the search was 'site:github.com angularjs form.$invalid not updating.' From personal experience the bugs on github are often very helpful as the standard is to provide working examples and workarounds - as in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. You've saved me a lot of (additional) grief :)