# Form validation with AngularJS and dynamic fields

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm stuck with strange problem regarding AngularJS form validation. If a dynamically added control (a textbox, for instance) requires validation and is removed from the form, the form will remain invalid if the removed control was invalid.

That last sentence is a bit confusing. See it in action with [this plnkr preview](http://embed.plnkr.co/qvCJZx44WkcTHiQjsnH7) (or see [the plnkr editor](http://plnkr.co/edit/qvCJZx44WkcTHiQjsnH7)).

I've checked the [FormController API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform.FormController). Based on the documentation, there's no method to provoke any kind of form validation status refresh, although the AngularJS source code defines methods like `$removeControl()` and `$setValidity()` in the FormController.

Is there a standard way to circumvent the validation issue?

Comment: Hi Humberto. So it seems you've worked with dynamic forms in AngularJS. ;) Could you please take a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/q/15843765/1153681?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this before, see this answer for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15192773/317180

Apparently this is an active bug.

A workaround is to provide a hidden counter that is incremented when elements are changed, this forces the form to revalidate:

In template:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-bind="abc" />
```

In controller:

```
$scope.remove = function(position) {
    $scope.items.splice(position, 1);
    $scope.abc += 1;
}
```