# Accessing parent formController in angular directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618318/pass-form-to-directive) I have found how to access parent form within link in a directive. But I need it in my controller and access to form validation, so I implement this:

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: '?^form',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    someVariable: '='
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
    scope.formCtrl = formCtrl;
  },
  controller: function ($scope) {
    $scope.someMethod = function () {
      if ($scope.formCtrl.$valid) {
        //Do something
      }
    }
  }
};
```

It´s the correct way to do that? there's a better way?

EDIT: I need isolated scope and I´m actually using `require: '?^form'`

Comment: If you wanted to do in that way then you should add `require: '^form'` in your directive, would give you an access.. But you really wanted to access form controller **OR** wanted to pass it inside isolated scope?

Comment: If you don't need to have isolated scope you can access it (form) directly.

Comment: I just edit my answer based on your comments.

Comment: Is other directive requiring this directive, if not then you can move the logic from the controller in the link function. If you really need the controller then you will need to do undefined check for the 'formCtrl' because the controller function runs before the link function.