# Using 'require' in angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

According to [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) (specifically, the table comparing directives to components), angular components allow requiring other directives (or is it only components?). However, components do not have a link function, which could give access to the required controller. [The source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/f31c5a3924629795cd9169e69b9e20efd4a9d927/src/ng/compile.js), contrary to documentation, seems to suggest that it is not possible to use 'require' when creating components. Which is true?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The cited source is outdated. As of 1.5.0, component controllers [can be required](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.0/src/ng/compile.js#L1096) in other components (the same applies to directives).

An example from the guide [shows the way how the components and directives should interact](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication) in 1.5 without the aid from `link`.

When [`require` object and `bindToController`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.0/src/ng/compile.js#L2423) are used together, required controller instances are assigned to current controller as properties.

Because this happens during directive linking, the required controllers aren't available in controller constructor, that's why [`$onInit` magic method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) is there. If it exists, [it is executed right after adding required controllers](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.0/src/ng/compile.js#L2431) to `this`.

Both

```
app.directive('someDirective', function () {
  return {
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {},
    controllerAs: 'someDirective',
    require: {
      anotherDirective: '^anotherDirective'
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
      console.log("You don't see me", this.anotherDirective);

      this.$onInit = function () {
        console.log("Now you do", this.anotherDirective);
      };
    }
  }
});
```

and

```
app.component('someComponent', {
  controllerAs: 'someComponent',
  require: {
    anotherDirective: '^anotherDirective'
  },
  controller: function ($scope) {
    console.log("You don't see me", this.anotherDirective);

    this.$onInit = function () {
      console.log("Now you do", this.anotherDirective);
    };
  }
});
```

declaration styles are on a par under the hood and can be used interchangeably in 1.5, and `component` is a concise one.