# Angular 1.x child Directive call method within parent Component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-components

I have an Angular 1.5 system comprising of several nested Components.  I now need to use a Directive (this needs to be an attribute) which will be embedded within a Component.

How can I call a function in the parent Component from the child Directive?  What is the correct syntax for somehow exposing a method in the parent Component so that an event in the child Directive can call it?

Comment: Via `require`. [RTM](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293680/using-require-in-angular-component .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS access parent scope from child controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller)

Answer (score 0):

You can use in child element
 `$scope.$emit('EventName', attrObject);` or `$rootScope.$broadcast('EventName', attrObject);`

And in parent controller

```
 $scope.$on('EventName', function(event, attrObject){ 
//your code calling function you want to use
}
```