# angular 1.6.4 component unit test with webpack not finding DirectiveProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, webpack

I am receiving this error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] **Unknown provider**: checkListDirectiveProvider <- 
>   checkListDirective
>   why would $componentController issue an unknown directive provider error?

[image]

Looking in the source code for angular mocks, the problem is here:

```
return function $componentController(componentName, locals, bindings, ident) {
  // get all directives associated to the component name
  var directives = $injector.get(componentName + 'Directive');
```

Why would `$injector` **try and find directives**, when I am registering a **component**?

```
module("app").component("checkList", new CheckListComponent());
```

### TL;DR

<sup>(for more background information)</sup>
My test (using webpack) is structured as follows:

```
var mocks = require("angular");
require("angular-mocks");
require("../app.js");
require("./CheckListComponent.js");

describe("component: check list component",
    function () {
        var q;
        var r;

        beforeEach(() => mocks.module("app"));
        beforeEach(inject(function (_$componentController_, $q, $rootScope) {
            $componentController = _$componentController_;
            q = $q;
            r = $rootScope;
        }));

        it("show question should calculate correct answers",
            function () {
                var bindings = {};
                var ctrl = $componentController("checkList", null, bindings);
                expect(ctrl.showQuestion).toBeDefined();
            });
    });
```

I am trying to understand why this is not working. Digging into the debugger I can see that `mocks.module("app")._invokeQueue` seems to contain the registered component, so why is `$componentController` unable to create it?

[image]

The complete source for the component (in typescript) is:

```
/**
 * the component wrapper.
 */
export class CheckListComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {

    controllerAs: string = "cl";
    bindings: any;
    controller: any;
    templateUrl: string;

    /**
     * @constructor create a new instance of the component.
     */
    constructor() {
        this.bindings = { checkList: "<" };
        this.controller = CheckListController;
        this.templateUrl = "compliance/checklist/component";
    }
}

module("app").component("checkList", new CheckListComponent());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here,

```
var mocks = require("angular");
```

This will cause `mocks.module("app")` to be `angular.module("app")`, which does nothing in tests. No module is loaded in tests, `app` units are not available for injection, including `checkList` component.

It should be

```
var angular = require("angular");
require("angular-mocks");
...
beforeEach(() => angular.mock.module("app"));
```

The error is caused by the fact that Angular components **are** directives (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35295114/3731501) for explanation), and directives **are** providers. All that `$componentController` does is getting an instance of a provider that contains directive definition object and instantiating its `controller` property.

This is what the error refers to:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: checkListDirectiveProvider <- checkListDirective

Comment: do you know what the equivalent set of ES6 import statements would look like? For instance `import { * } as angular from "angular";`, assuming I am using webpack (as above)

Comment: Yes, it is. Usually lib files are included in Karma config, so there's no need to import them in every spec file.

Comment: @Jim the correct sintax of import that works for me was without braces:
`import * as angular from "angular";`