# dymanic value passing in templateUrl in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

What i am doing is creating one custom control with form-name, name, model, title attributes , that replace with a template with the textbox with respective validations

HMTL:

```
 <form name="usrForm" novalidate>

            <input-req form-name="usrForm" ctrl-name="myname" ng-model="user.name" my-title="Name"></input-req>

        </form>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("demo", []).controller('demoCtrl', ["$scope", function ($scope) {

}]);
app.directive("inputReq", function () {

        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: function (element, attrs) {
                return '<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ \'has-error\' : ' + attrs.formName + '.' + attrs.ctrlName + '.$invalid && !' + attrs.formName + '.' + attrs.ctrlName + '.$pristine }"><label>' + attrs.myTitle + '</label><input type="text" name="' + attrs.ctrlName + '" placeholder="' + attrs.myTitle + '" class="form-control" ng-model="' + attrs.ngModel + '" required><p ng-show="' + attrs.formName + '.' + attrs.ctrlName + '.$invalid && !' + attrs.formName + '.' + attrs.ctrlName + '.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p></div>';
            },
        }
    });
```

This was working fine, i need to separate the HTML, i created a new html and shifted the HTML but its not working

How to do it, any one kindly suggest some solutions

I TRIED THIS:

```
app.directive("inputReq", function () {

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            form: '=formName',
            name: '=ctrlName',
            model: '=ngModel',
            title: '=myTitle'
        },

        templateUrl: "input-req.html",

        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.attrs = attr;
        }
    };

});
```

input-req.html:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : {{attrs.formName}}.{{attrs.ctrlName}}.$invalid && !{{attrs.formName}}.{{attrs.ctrlName}}.$pristine }">
    <label>{{attrs.myTitle}}</label>
    <input type="email" name="name" placeholder="{{attrs.ngModel}}" class="form-control" ng-model="{{attrs.ngModel}}" required>
    <p ng-show="{{attrs.formName}}.{{attrs.ctrlName}}.$invalid && !{{attrs.formName}}.{{attrs.ctrlName}}.$pristine" class="help-block">You title is required.</p>
</div>
```

THROWN ERROR:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2
>   of the expression [{{attrs.ngModel}}] starting at [{attrs.ngModel}}].

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular.js directive dynamic templateURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl)

Comment: This question/answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618318/pass-form-to-directive