# getting the name of the form tag from an HTML element within a directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting the ngModel name, but I also want to get the name of the form to which the element with the "validacion" directive belongs.

I strictly need to get the name of the form to which the HTML element belongs. I can have several forms so I need a dynamic solution. thank you very much

```
.directive('validacion', function ($timeout,$rootScope,validacionCampos,$compile) {

      return {
          restrict: 'AE',
          require: 'ngModel',

          link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                  if (!ngModel){
                          console.log("no hay modal")
                  return;          
          }
```

Comment: you could try element.closest(form).attr('name');

Answer (score 0):

The following code should fetch you the value of `name` attribute of the form to which the `validacion` element belongs:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    console.log(element.closest('form').attr('name'));
  }
```

**EDIT** If jQuery is not there in the project, use the `parent()` function instead, provided that the directive element is the direct child of the `<form>` tag:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    console.log(element.parent().attr('name'));
  }
```

Comment: ..closest is a function of jquery? `element.closest is not a function`

Comment: I dont use jquery

Comment: element is a wrapper for using jQuery in Angular. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: yes, and if jQuery is not available, angularJS supports jqLite, a subset of jQuery. It seems `closest` is not available in jqLite, so either use jQuery, or use `parent()` instead. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You should require the formCtrl:

```
require: '^form',
```

and use this in the link function of your directive:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
    console.log(formCtrl);
}
```

For full details on passing forms into directives, see similar problem being solved at Stackoverflow here: 
[Pass form to directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618318/pass-form-to-directive)

EDIT: With AngularJS 1.5.x you have different syntax (being able to skip the link function), just an citation of https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021943/priidu-neemre great answer, (see more with above mentioned link):

```
return {
  restrict : 'EA',
  require : {
    form : '^'
  },
```