# AngularJs dynamic form generation with validation

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to generate form dynamically and use validation at the same time. The problem that  I have now is that the input attribute `name='{{key}}'` is not interpolated by the validation.

```
<div ng-repeat="options in formObject">
     <input type='radio' ng-model='ranodm' name='{{key}}'>
</div>
```

I know that I should use ng-form if I want a dynamic form, however I am having hard time to understand it. I am adding my simple plnkr example of what I am trying to achieve. It would be nice if someone would show how to solve this using ng-form or other method.

[http://plnkr.co/edit/faG89bmu18nNNODVRV3x](http://plnkr.co/edit/faG89bmu18nNNODVRV3x?p=preview)

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Fields added dynamically are not registered on FormController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843765/angularjs-fields-added-dynamically-are-not-registered-on-formcontroller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer from reading through this SO post: [Dynamic validation and name in a form with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378401/dynamic-validation-and-name-in-a-form-with-angularjs)

I ended up using the dynamicName directive to work around this problem so I could use a UUID of as the name of the field.  Here's a plnkr and the directive I used.  I can't take credit for the directive, I found it on that other post.

http://plnkr.co/edit/RFrRXp2kWkP1Mefwl3Kn?p=info

```
myApp.directive('dynamicName', function($compile, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        terminal: true,
        priority: 100000,
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            var name = $parse(elem.attr('dynamic-name'))(scope);
            elem.removeAttr('dynamic-name');
            elem.attr('name', name);
            $compile(elem)(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through following link this will help.

http://www.benlesh.com/2013/03/angular-js-validating-form-elements-in.html