# How to write an angular custom directive that encapsulates an input in the template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to write an angular directive that essentially will output a label and the input along with validation code.  When I do this, I get weird behavior.

First, for my test case, I have hard coded my directive to put ng-minlength on the input.  When I do this, for some reason, the model does not bind.  If I take it off, it will bind correctly.

Second, I have set the name property to an attribute specified on the custom directive.  This prevents the error handling from working.

In this plunkr, I have an example of what is going on:

http://plnkr.co/edit/BGxB5fENL5L6G7FcvPR5?p=preview

- Label1 - Demonstrates how hard coding the name property causes the error handling to work.  It also demonstrates how including the `ng-minlength` causes the model value not to be bound.
- Label2 - Demonstrates that removing the `ng-minlength` will allow the model value to be bound.
- Label3 - Demonstrates that dynamically binding the `name` property causes the error handling to break.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.  I am hoping I am just missing something simple, but I cannot seem to find any good examples of how to do this.

Comment: Check this library out for something that already does a lot of what you are looking for: https://github.com/kelp404/angular-validator

Comment: Thanks JoseM.  That might help with the validation side of what I am trying to do, but for now, I am trying to get a directive that will output the elements to represent an entire prompt and answer along with validation.  Mainly to simplify my forms code because I have a lot of similar forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Empty invalid fields

According to this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/fsvIhzEPvuA you are getting the expected behavior of ng-minlength. If your initial value causes a validation error with ng-minlength then ng-minlength returns it as undefined. (this explains the issue of label 1 and 2 fields having no value)

#### Missing validation info with dynamic input names

The problem with label 2 and 3 is that angular doesn't support validation with dynamic element names. It looks like this is an issue a few people are having and trying to make angular do something about. There is more information and a work around here:

[AngularJS: Fields added dynamically are not registered on FormController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843765/angularjs-fields-added-dynamically-are-not-registered-on-formcontroller)

(This should explain the issues with the validation information being missing form label fields 2 and 3)

Comment: Excellent!  The does explain why the model was not binding to the control and I verified by setting the initial value of the model to a valid value.  However that still leaves me with the problem in Label3.  You will notice in the output that value3 does not contain a value for $error.  I would expect it to contain a value the same as value1.  Am I missing something or is this a correct assumption?

Comment: I'm glad that i could help =) The reason that items 2 and 3 don't have any validation data is because they have dynamic names. I have updated my answer with this information.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I can tell now why this was so frustrating not being aware of this behavior.  Good news is they appear to have fixed this in 1.3 so once I get moved to that version I can drop my workaround.  For now, I decided to just $compile() my directive template in the link function and this obviously fixes my issue.  Thanks for your help!